# Entity Framework - Why does EF use LEFT OUTER JOIN's in a 1-to-1 relationship?

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, entity-framework, devart

Why does .NET Entity Framework produce SQL that uses a subquery and left outer join on a simple 1-to-1 relationship? I expected to see a simple join on the two tables. I'm using [Devart Dotconnect for Oracle](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/). Any ideas?

Below is the output I see courtesy of the [EFTracingProvider](http://blogs.msdn.com/jkowalski/archive/2009/06/11/tracing-and-caching-in-entity-framework-available-on-msdn-code-gallery.aspx):

```
SELECT
1 AS C1,
"Join1".USER_ID1 AS USER_ID,
...
FROM  "MY$NAMESPACE".MYTABLE1 "Extent1"
INNER JOIN  (...
    FROM  "MY$NAMESPACE".MYTABLE2 "Extent2"
    LEFT OUTER JOIN "MY$NAMESPACE".MYTABLE1 "Extent3" ON "Extent2".OTHER_ID = "Extent3".OTHER_ID ) 
    "Join1" ON "Extent1".OTHER_ID = "Join1".OTHER_ID1
WHERE "Extent1".USER_ID = :EntityKeyValue1
-- EntityKeyValue1 (dbtype=String, size=6, direction=Input) = "000000"
```

Comment: Are your tables properly foreign-keyed?

Comment: Yes, there is a foreign key from MYTABLE1 to MYTABLE2.

Comment: Is this from an EF query? Or simply a Single()?

Comment: Please show the query *and* the mapping.

Comment: It's actually the query created by a call to Load().

Comment: Is it an optional 1-to-1 relationship? That might explain the left join.

Comment: Yes, rephrasing what Martin asked, is your ForeignKey field (MyTable1.Other_ID) NULLable?

Comment: Is it an optional 1-to-1 relationship after all?

Comment: EF uses outer joins when joining views even if the foreign key exists. Are you using views?

Answer (score 0):

In database theory, it is assumed that in a one-to-one relationship, A row on one side must be created before the corresponding row on the other side.  If you didn't use an outer join, then you could never list the rows which had no match.